# Deploy JS from firebug to the site

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, firefox, firebug

I have a question, is there a way, how I can deploy ( upload ) JS script from Firebug plugin(Chrome or Firefox) into the targeted site?

Why I need it? Because I am not an a part of this site developers, but I need to modify some scripts on this site for my own tasks...

Is there any solution?

Comment: No. Imagine what consequences would it have.

Comment: Not possible. Ask the developers to improve the flexibility of what they have made.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To persist client-side code *only for yourself* you can use browser add-ons such as [Greasemonkey](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/greasemonkey/).

Comment: hmmm, just wat I want! Thanks!